# I already trained a large data set in jupyter notebook using vs-code. How can I save the trained dataset.?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, dcgan

[This is the information about the trained dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkQ4i.png)

It took me 24 hrs to train the whole dataset. I guess its fully trained but its still showing (1150/1583).

Nevertheless how can I save my progress so that I don't have to retrain

I tried saving the code once but the model started training again.

```py
## Save Model
torch.save(netG, 'C:/6th sem/TT(L)/Face detection/imgGen.pt')
torch.save(netD, 'C:/6th sem/TT(L)/Face detection/imgDis.pt')
```

So I used this I'm not sure it will work or not.

Comment: why post an image of a bunch of text lines

Comment: but if you don't load the model if the save file found it will train again

Answer (score 0):

You can use `joblib` to save and load model.

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
```

And use method [joblib.dump()](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.dump.html) and [joblib.load()](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.load.html)